# How to find the representative standard deviation from a pool of standard deviation value for a repeated process?

Tags: r, mean, standard-deviation

I have a process A that captures 86400 sample points per day from a system B. I am repeating the process A for 23 days. After 23 days, I have 23 mean and 23 standard deviation (sd) values. I am trying to come up with a normal distribution for this entire process. For constructing a normal distribution, I need a representative mean and standard deviation value. For representative mean, I can take the average of all 23 means, but I am not sure what will be the representative for 23 standard deviations.

Is it right to consider average of all standard deviation values as the representative standard deviation for the entire process?

All the 86400 samples points are random numbers between 0 and 20.

Comment: Why not just treat the 23 samples as one sample?

Comment: Idea is to see the daily behaviour.

Comment: Err...how would taking the average of the SD show you daily behaviour?

Comment: Also this question is better suited to math stackexchange or even cross validated.

Comment: You can't just take the average of SDs. There is a formula to do this but you need to work with variances. Also with the amount of data points you each day it's going to be alotnof computing! I'm trying to find the formula for you.

Comment: Read this: http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/14523-An-average-of-standard-deviations

Comment: I've voted to migrate to [stats.se]. The appropriateness of statistical methods is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @I.K I'm not saying that taking the average for SD is right.  Instead,  I think it has to be something else.  Weighted square root is suggested under the link you posted.  I'm still searching answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you mean by "trying to come up with a normal distribution for this entire process", but I hope this helps:

You have a list means, to get the representative mean, you are doing the right thing by taking the average of them. To get the representative of standard deviation, take the 23 means that you calculated and find the standard deviation of them as a data set. Below is some R code I hope you can translate to fit your needs.

```
data <- processA_runFor23Days()
daily_means <- getMeanForEachDay(data)  #this should be a vector of length 23  
sd(daily_means)
```

Where "daily_means" are the means for each day. I think this should be ok since each day has the same number of data points.

EDIT:
To be more clear, lets say that you have the means for each of the 23 days

```
  > daily_means
 [1] 0.59073346 0.66107694 0.32187724 0.60259824 0.92803502 0.82414235
 [7] 0.21125403 0.61161841 0.48346220 0.86058580 0.87253787 0.94609922
[13] 0.40849556 0.96766218 0.49403126 0.38261995 0.02554012 0.19892710
[19] 0.55517159 0.71836176 0.53599262 0.67525105 0.25059165
```

Ignore the the standard deviations for each of the days, they no longer matter. Your new distribution is now the the means from each day. So take the mean and the standard deviation of these 23 numbers.

```
> mean(daily_means)
[1] 0.5707246
> sd(daily_means)
[1] 0.2624342
```

Comment: this is exactly how summary statistics in excel calculates the SD. This is one possible way. Just one question, if I use this method then I have to calculate the SD on the 23rd day data set using average mean of 23 days? Aren't we neglecting the variability information that was generated for 22 days?

Comment: Jwilley44: It is known that if you repeat a process n number of times, given that the n is large, any distribution can be converted to a normalized distribution. There's a mathematics proof for this somewhere. I'm just trying to apply that to my data set, to further deduce the probability of data crossing a certain number. That's what I meant by generating normalized distribution for the process.

Comment: The theorem you are talking about is the Central Limit Theorem. Have a look at the wikipedia page and see if my answer makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. I see what you saying. However, I don't understand why to take standard deviation over the 23 means.

Comment: The same reason you take a standard deviation over any distribution. The 23 means ARE your distribution now, it doesnt make sense to take the standard deviation of anything else. Why are you doing this process? Are you empirically proving the Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: No, not proving the central limit theorem. Actually, I am trying to use it to solve a bandwidth allocation problem. The data points are in unit Megabits (Mbps) . There are 3 fixed bandwidth of 20 Mbps that are available for 9 sources (traffic generators). I am trying to characterize the behaviour of each source to see what are the best sources that can be placed together on the fixed bandwidth of 20 Mbps and in what number.